# How to improve performance of pyspark UDFs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following **pyspark** code.

```
# Reading contents of a text file into an RDD
data_set_rdd = spark_context.textFile(full_file_path) 

# Read the header line
header = data_set_rdd.first()

# Construct the schema
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in header.split(",")]
schema = StructType(fields)

# Filter empty lines
non_empty_lines = self.data_set_rdd.filter(lambda line: len(line)>0)

# Filter header record from the RDD
contents_rdd = non_empty_lines.filter(lambda line: line != header)

# Split the RDD into columns based on delimiter
delimited_contents_rdd = contents_rdd.map(lambda k: k.split(delimiter))

# Convert RDD into DataFrame  
contents_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(delimited_contents_rdd, schema)

# Create a function
def check_value(val):
    if val > 220:
        return 220
    else:
        return val

# Register the function as a pyspark udf
check_val = udf(check_value, IntegerType())

# Add a column to the dataframe which uses the check_val function to perform some computation
final_df = contents_df.withColumn("transformed_voltage", check_val (contents_df["voltage"]))

final_df.show(10)
```

Now the step where the UDF is called to add the column (withColumn) takes a long time to complete. It takes around 10 mins to complete. I am running this on my laptop with 8 GB RAM, 4 Cores.

I have only 10 records in my input file.

My text file is of the following schema with 2 columns [timestamp,voltage]

If I replace the UDF with a pyspark built-in function like WHEN, it completes within a few milliseconds.

I was expecting UDFs to be slow, but can they be so slow ?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated because I will end up writing custom UDFs for my project.

Comment: In general, it is always recommended to have UDF's in either Scala or Java, due to lot of activities needed if they were in Python.

Comment: a) You shouldn't use udfs unless you have to b) 10 minutes vs. milliseconds / 10 records is not reproducible with this code.